# Typescript: return multiple type regarding to parameter value

Tags: typescript

I want to get specified return type regarding to specified parameter like following.

```
function Fetch(isAsync:boolean){
  return isAsync ? AsyncGet : Get;
}
```

If app runs let func = Fetch(true), it expects func to be of AsyncGet type, but the return value type is AsyncGet | Get.

I cannot call func() for it has incompatible signature from AsyncGet and Get.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types)

```
function Fetch<T extends boolean>(isAsync: T): T extends true ? AsyncGet : Get {
  // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want function overloading:

```
function Fetch(isAsync:true): AsyncGet;
function Fetch(isAsync:false): Get;
function Fetch(isAsync:boolean): AsyncGet | Get{
  return isAsync ? AsyncGet : Get;
}
```